Unable to create a constant value of type 'Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmModel' for OData Select Request
I'm using OData 8.2.5 with .NET 6 and I'm trying to return results from my controller shown below. When I hit /odata/MyType it works, but if I hit /odata/MyType?$select=Id, I get the error in the title, System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmModel'.
If I return a List and call ToList() on my set then the select works, but I can't afford to load everything into memory before the select filters are applied. I want to make it work with IQueryable. Any help is appreciated!
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Formatter;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Results;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Controllers;


namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class MyTypeController : ODataController
    {
        private string _apiKey = string.Empty;

        public MyTypeController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _apiKey = configuration.GetValue<string>("apikey");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<MyTypeEntity> Get()
        {
            return BuildFilteredDbSet();
        }

      
    }
}


BuildFilteredDbSet.cs
public IQueryable<T> BuildFilteredDbSet()
{
    return _entityDataContext.Set<T>();
}

Program.cs
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(options =>
{
    options.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().SetMaxTop(null).Count()
    .AddRouteComponents("odata", modelBuilder.GetEdmModel());
}
);



Does this link helped you? It points to NewtonsoftJson. Could you pls help check it?

Yep, I've seen this. I tried this solution and ended up removing NetwonsoftJson all together and replacing it with System.Text.Json but no luck

Do you try .AddODataNewtonsoftJson() like what the link mentioned?

I did, but I still have the same issue

Sorry I don't have any other ideas then..
